# Mongo Db design (embed vs references)

Tags: performance, mongodb, web-applications, database-design

I've read a lot of documents, Q&A etc about that topic (embed or to use references).
I understand the points why you should use one or another approach, but I can't see that someone discuss (asked) similar case:

I have 2 (`A` and `B`) entities and relation between them is ONE_TO_MANY (`A` could belongs to many `B`), I can use `embed` (denormalization approach) and it's ok (I clearly understand it), but what if I would like (later) to modify one of used, into many `B` documents, `A` document field ? Modify it does not mean replace `A` by `A'`, it means some changes into exactly `A` record. It means that (in `embed` case) I have to apply such changes in all `B` documents which had `A` version already.

based on description here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-example-one-to-many

```
What If later we would like to change used in many documents address:name field ? 
What If we need the list of available addresses in the system ?
```

**How fast that operations will be done in MongoDb ?**

Answer (score 0):

It's based on what operations are used mostly. If you are inserting and selecting lot of documents and there is a possibility, that e.g. once a month you will need to modify many nested sub-documents, I think that storing `A` inside `B` is good practice, it's what mongodb is supposed to be. You will save lot of time just selecting one document without needing to join another ones and slower update once a time you can stand without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

How fast the update ops will be is obviously dependent on volume of data.

Other considerations as to whether to use embedded docs or references is whether the volume of data in a single document would exceed 16mb. That's a lot of documents mind.

In some cases however, it simply doesn't make sense to denormalise entire documents especially where they're used/referenced elsewhere.

Take a `User` document for example, you wouldn't usually denormalise all user attributes across each collection that needs to reference a user.  Instead you reference the user [with maybe some denormalised user detail].

Obviously each additional denormalised value (unless it was an audit) would need to be updated when the referenced User changes, but you could queue the updates for a background process to deal with - rather than making the caller wait.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in some more advice as to speed.

If you have a sub-document called A that is embedded in lots of documents - and you want to change instances of A ...

- Careful that the documents don't grow too much with a change. That will hurt performance if A grows too big because it will force Mongo to move the document in memory.
- It obviously depends on how many embedded instances you have. The more you have, the slower it will be.
- It depends on how you match the sub-document. If you are finding A without an index, it's going to be slow. If you are using range operators to identify it, it will be slow.
- Someone already mentioned the size of documents will most likely affect the speed.

The best advice I heard about whether to link or embed was this ... if the entity (A in this case) is mutable ... if it is going to mutate/change often ... then link it, don't embed it.